# Template Specialisation no matching function call to

Tags: c++, c++11

Trying to make a template specialisation for vectors but getting a compiler error.

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<double, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
AttributeValue from(double value) {
    ...       
}

      
template<typename N, typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<std::vector<N>, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
AttributeValue from(std::vector<N> value) {
    ...
    for (N item: value) {
        AttributeValue val = from(item);
    }       
}
```

When trying to call to convert my vector...

```
MyClass mclass;
mclass.from<double>(1); // compiles
std::vector<double> vect{1};
mclass.from<std::vector<double>>(vect); // error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::from<std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > >(std::vector<double>&)’
```

Comment: For the second overload, what is `T` for?  You're not providing it and there is no way for it to be deduced.

Comment: Yup you're right that served no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @NathanOliver the `typedef T` served no purpose.
Overall I managed to get this working by doing the following:

```
template<typename T>
        AttributeValue from(std::vector<T> value) {
    ...
    for (T item: value) {
        AttributeValue val = from<T>(item); // <T> here is required.
    }  
}
```

```
std::vector<double> vect{1};
builder.from<double>(vect);
```

Comment: noted, thank you. In this particular code it is by design as the function is part of a builder and thus want input args to be immutable (even to the original caller).